# Table stretches container when inside of tab-content

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently trying to create a tabbed menu within a container. What I am not understanding is that when it is just the table in the container, it behaves fine. But when I put the table inside of a tab, it stretches all the way to the end of the browser window.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="myTabs" style="margin-left:15px" !important>
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a data-target="#createContainer" aria-controls="createContainer" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" style="color:black">Create a Route</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a data-target="#importContainer" aria-controls="importContainer" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" style="color:black">Import a Route</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="createContainer">
        <div style="padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default" style="padding-bottom: 4px" ng-click="capture.saveChanges()">Apply Changes</button>
            <div style="padding-top: 4px">
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="captureTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Index</th>
                            <th>elem1</th>
                            <th>elem2</th>
                            <th>elem3</th>
                            <th>elem4</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="x in capture.railLines track by x.ASSET_PK" ng-click="capture.selectLine(x.ASSET_PK)">
                            <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
                            <td>{{x.elem1}}</td>
                            <td>{{x.elem2}}</td>
                            <td>{{x.elem3}}</td>
                            <td><a ng-click="capture.deleteLine(x.elem1)" href="javascript:void(0);">{{capture.isOutOfOrder('sym')}}</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The header of the table will respond to the `max-width`, `width`, `word-break`, `table-layout` flags I put in for the style on `<table>`, but the body seems to always reject it.

EDIT **CSS:**

```
.nav-tabs > li {
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.nav-tabs {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a {
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.tab-content thead, .tab-content tbody tr {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.tab-content table tbody td, .tab-content table thead td {
    width: 100px;
}

.tab-content tbody {
    /*height:130px;*/
}

th, td {
    padding: 10px;
}

    table thead td,
    .stickyheader td {
        background: #222;
        color: #f4ba05;
        padding: 8px;
        margin: 0;
    }

    table tbody td {
        padding: 3px 7px 2px;
    }

    table tbody .alt td {
        color: #000;
    }

    table .highlight {
        background-color: #ffff94;
    }

    table .permHighlight {
        background-color: #ff530f;
    }

thead, tbody tr {
    /*display: table;
        width: 100%;*/
}

thead {
    width: calc( 100% - 1em );
    /*width:1320px;*/
}

    tbody td, thead td {
        /*width: 100px;*/
        border-right: 1px solid black;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }

.tab-content thead, .tab-content tbody tr {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.tab-content table tbody td, .tab-content table thead td {
    width: 100px;
}

.tab-content tbody {
    /*height:130px;*/
}
```

Comment: Can you post the CSS that goes with this? With just the HTML it won't behave as such.

Comment: Just edited the question. It seems that taking out the last three blocks of CSS code makes it behave, but I'm not sure what the problem is. I suspect something is conflicting, but I'm not sure because I'm new to CSS and this was an inherited project that came with no documentation.